# Link Documents and Desktop Directories on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, login-script

I'm working on our login script for our OS X 10.5 deployment and I want to redirect the user's Documents and Desktop directories to their network home directory.  In the login script I have a line that attempts deletes the old folders before creating the link but I get an permissions error.  If I try to delete the directories through the finder I get the following error message:

""Folder Name" can't be modified or deleted because it is required by Mac OS X".

Is there some way to allow me to remove these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Standard" folders in a user's home directory have access control entries that block deletion.  You can use `chmod -N` to clear their ACLs before deleting...

Answer (score 0):

From my brief experience with OS X Server (10.5), I think you'll want to actually create the users on the Server and have their desktops authenticate against the server with Open Directory. From there, you can set up their home directory to be a network folder and authorize the use of offline/mobile access if desired (if they were to take the desktop to somewhere the Server could not be accessed). If you're making the user authentication method on each desktop and then writing a shell script that symlinks to files on a network file server, I'm afraid OS X will not let you delete necessary local account directories.